# ASP.NET 5 & Entity Framework 7 Seeding data not in sequential code order

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET 5 RC1 and Entity Framework 7 RC1

I have the following class method

```
public class MySeedData
{
    private MyDb_context;

    public MySeedData(MyDb db)
    {
        _context = db;
    }


    public void DoSeedData()
    {
        if (!_context.Table1s.Any())
        {
           _context.Table1s.AddRange(
              new Table1{ Table1Name= "AAAA" },
              new Table2{ Table1Name= "BBBB" },
              new Table3{ Table1Name= "CCCC" }
            );
        }
    }
```

and then in the Configure method of my Startup.cs

```
mySeeder.DoSeedData();
```

However when I query the db I notice that the rows were not created in the order the code is listed. The Id gets generated by the database.

Output is

> 1 BBBB
>
> 2 AAAA
>
> 3 CCCC

For tables with lots of seeding data, the order looks even very random.

I assume this is to do with asynchronous processing.

The question is how do I force it to be synchronous and sequential?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one by one instead of using the AddRange that way you can guarantee the order